# Jasper - sort by field with char and int values

Tags: sorting, jasper-reports

I have a report which uses a SP to get a list of fields numbered from 1 to ~1700 but also including some char values (H44, HH4 etc.)  The db stores these as char(5) types. The report field class is java.lang.String. The output is pretty much random and I would like to sort the fields ascending, starting with the numbers.   I am using JasperSoft Studio 6.2.1.

From the Outline view I selected Sort Fields.  I created a new sortField using the name of the field I want to sort by.  It shows Type as a 'field' and  Order is sorting 'asc'.   These are the only options in the properties for the sortField.

In the Source it shows:

```
<sortField name = "myfield"/>
```

When I run the report I get the fields listed in order, but only by the first digits.   It shows 1,10,100,1002,1003,1004...103,1030(there is no 101,102,1001).  It put 2,3,4,5 etc. elsewhere in the list.

I tried creating a variable and converting the string but I found I cannot use:

```
Integer.parseInt("myField")
```

since it seems to choke as soon as it hits a non-int. In fact I get an JRExpressionEvalException when I try to run it.  It seems the string in this case is "1511 " - with a space at the end?

I can't control the SP so is there a way to sort this mess?

Comment: I would try fix it in query, it seems like the result your are giving to jasper is not sortable..

Comment: A query ... from the proc results?

Comment: It depends on where you want the H44, HH4 and the other non-numeric values to appear in your sorted series. I understand numbers should be sorted as numbers, but you don't say how non-numbers should be sorted. I assume values that are not numbers should be sorted alphabetically, after all numbers. I suggest you sort by a String variable in which you append enough zeros at the beginning of the value like this: "0000" + $F{myField}).substring($F{myField}.length())

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today while creating an Ad Hoc View on Jasper Server. I've solved it as follows: 
1) create a calculated field which contains the full string (e.g. "--" resulting in "1-2-3", "2-2-3", "10-2-3", ...)
2) add this field as a column to the report
3) sort the report's resultset as follows: value1, value2, value3
Is this helpful for your problem?

Sven